# stringstream bug in VC9? "Cannot access private member"

Tags: c++, stl, stringstream, visual-c++-2008

```
std::string str;
std::stringstream strm(str);
```

I get this error:

> Error 11  error C2248:
>   'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios'
>   : cannot access private member
>   declared in class
>   'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'   c:\program
>   files\microsoft visual studio
>   9.0\vc\include\sstream    517

If I use istringstream, same happens.

Compiler: Visual C++ 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to copy a stream. This is not possible as the copy constructors are private.

Comment: Yep. And the VC9 didn't link to the right code, I tried to do something like this:
boost::archive::xml_iarchive xml(GetStream(igFilePath));

where GetStream would copy a string stream.

Nice catch, STL!

Comment: @mannicken, so the code you posted was NOT the code on which you were getting that error...?!  Wow -- way to go, let's select for mind-reading -- I'm amazed that somebody managed to see past your code to what was REALLY happening...

Comment: My bad (well, not my bad exactly but still). I narrowed down the problem by removing stuff that didn't cause it and made a mistake.

Comment: @mannicken: why was this the accepted answer to the question posted? While it does solve your problem, it doesn't answer the question you originally posted.

Comment: I second @Alex and @kitchen: @mannicken, could you please edit your original question to show an example of the actual error?  As it stands, your question is not particularly informative.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    std::string str;
    std::stringstream strm( str );

    return 0;
}
```

Compiles fine with no errors/warnings for me in VS 2008. Can you post the full code?